# styles and theme

Tags: android

I still not understanding the parent role in the android styles I have put my XML code into the style XML which works well. I have been trying to get my head round android styles and I just not getting it. Any help would be great.

ps. I have been reading all about styles on the net. But the information is good but could be a lot better

http://imageshack.us/a/img843/3083/holo.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style name="LLayout1">
```

In your style.xml just replace the above line with below line

```
<style name="LLayout1" parent="android:Theme">
```

This is because every style in XML must have a parent type.

Comment: right so lets say i make many styles. will the parent just be the same for them all. thank you soo much Agarwal

Comment: no, every style must have parent attribute but may differ about the value

Comment: right ok . AGARWAL  do you  have a good video or site you can show me. just so i can get my head round it .(not the android site example)

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DQ4CRSBwLo   very good for understanding android styles & themes 5*